# Should we use save after setter

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am taking a large amount of data using findall method using iterator and changing some values(setter) in that entity.

Should I explicitly call respository.save(iterator) to save in database

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Are you within a transaction context? If so, then no, the context will pick up the changes made to entities read in through it and save them when the transaction commits. Otherwise, yes, you have to find a way to get your changes within a transactional context, and save is one way to do so.